# bash get first word last line

Tags: bash, changelog

I got a bash script and I started to write a changelog to keep track of changes.

I added in the script a function that echoes `"Script version --> "`
But I have to manually edit it.

So I would need a function to get the first word until space of the last line and store it as `$CURRENTVERSION`

Changelog syntax is:

```
v-0.3.2 Added x, y.

v-0.3.2.1 Fixed y.

v-0.4 Added z.
```

Briefly I would need to store `v-0.4` as `$CURRENTVERSION`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '{w=$1} END{print w}' file
```

OR using sed:

```
sed -n '$s/^\([^ ]*\).*$/\1/p' file
```

Comment: LOL sed is way too complex, is there a wiki somewere? (I don't like too much to use what i don't know/understand pretty good)
Tanks to the awk example you told me i would use this:
    currentver=(`awk 'END{print}' changelog.txt`)


Cause i need to keep $1 empty, and then currentver[0] would be what i need; Is this a good way?

Comment: Yes awk is far more simple here.

Comment: wouldn't `-r` with `sed` be better? it's won't require escaping brackets.

Comment: Also `awk` will process entire file, isn't it? what if change_log is too long! just hypothetical query. I would have preferred `sed` or `tail` with `grep`

Comment: I think you would need to measure performance to determine if the entire file was being processed to reach the end. In some sense, all line-oriented programs need to read from the beginning of the file to reach the end; binary search coupled with `seek()` could be used to start later, if you can determine that doing so would not miss any earlier lines required by the program.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like awk or sed, you can do this:

```
tail -n1 file | cut -d' ' -f1
```

But really, awk and sed are better tools for the job...

Comment: YEAH i tink i would use `awk 'END{print w}' changelog.txt | cut -d' ' -f1`

Comment: The only time I wouldn't use awk or sed for this, would be if I was on an embedded system where they weren't installed, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

bash:

```
read CURRENTVERSION rest < <(tail -1 changelog)
```

Comment: Tanks this also is a valid alternative!

Answer (score 0):

```
CURRENTVERSION=$( perl -anle 'print $F[0] if eof' changelog )
echo $CURRENTVERSION 
v-0.4
```